# StyleSheet for QWidget doesn't work in Qt

Tags: qt

I have set the `StyleSheet` in `Designer`...

and the preview show the effect what i want, but when it run... the effect is change to default. why ?

```
QWidget#BasicInfo{
    background-color: white;
}
```

and the i put it into QStackedWidget, may be the cause of it?

i.e the `stylesheet` doesn't work...what is the reason ?

Thank you...

Here is the Designer..

[image]

Comment: hi there. i actually have the same problem. did you solved it? i only can see color changes in Designer but not in application.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check in the generated ui file (e.g. ui_basicinfo.h), there is the code that call the *setStyleSheet* ? Sometimes, the ui code is not updated or there is a multiple ui files of the same class in different subfolders (depending on your project structure).

Answer (score 0):

you can rebuild the project(Clean,Qmake,build).